# javac not working in windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt, javac

I'm trying to use `javac` with the windows command prompt, but it's not working.

After adding the directory `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\"` to the end of the `PATH` environment variable, the `java` command works fine, but using `javac` gives me the following error:

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

If you added it in the control panel while your command prompt was open, that won't affect your current command prompt. You'll need to exit and re-open or simply do:

```
set "path=%path%;c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin"
```

By way of checking, execute:

```
echo %path%
```

from your command prompt and let us know what it is.

Otherwise, make sure there *is* a javac in that directory by trying:

```
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\javac.exe"
```

from the command prompt. You can also tell *which* executable (if any) is being used with the command:

```
for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i
```

This is a neat trick similar to the `which` and/or `whence` commands in some UNIX-type operating systems.

Comment: ah yes, all i had to do was re-open the command prompt and it worked fine, thanks!

Comment: +1. The "for %i in (java.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i" just saved my day. I'm just a occasional Windows user and I just did not know there's could be yet another hidden java.exe in c:\windows\system :)

Comment: The above set path command does not work for me under windows 7. I had to use set path="%path%;c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin. That is without quotes! I am not familiar with windows command line but it seems that quotes are preserved. So having them in the %path% will make it entirely unusable.

Comment: @user716468, There is a GUI way to do this in windows instead of command line. If you are on windows 7, just type var in start menu search and click on Edit Environment Variables. If you are on Windows XP, right click My Computer, Click on properties, go to advanced tab and click on the Environment variables button on the bottom side. There you can find two list boxes. Find out the one with name PATH from the bottom list box and click on Edit. Now append the path to your _JDK_ preceded by a semicolon. You're Done!

Comment: there is also a "where" command in recent windows command lines

Answer (score 87):

Windows OS searches the current directory and the directories listed in the PATH environment variable for executable programs. JDK's programs (such as Java compiler javac.exe and Java runtime java.exe) reside in directory "\bin" (where  denotes the JDK installed directory, e.g., C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx). You need to include the "\bin" directory in the PATH.

To edit the PATH environment variable in Windows XP/Vista/7/8:

1. Control Panel ⇒ System ⇒ Advanced system settings
2. Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ Environment Variables
3. In "System Variables", scroll down to select "PATH" ⇒ Edit

(( now read the following 3 times before proceeding, **THERE IS NO UNDO** ))

In "Variable value" field, INSERT "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx\bin" (Replace xx with the upgrade number and VERIFY that this is your JDK's binary directory!!!) IN FRONT of all the existing directories, followed by a semi-colon (;) which separates the JDK's binary directory from the rest of the existing directories.
DO NOT DELETE any existing entries; otherwise, some existing applications may not run.

```
Variable name  : PATH
Variable value : c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx\bin;[existing entries...]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For Step 4. I found that I had to select not jre<yournumber>, but jdk<yournumber>. Then everything else worked fine.

Comment: Neat and Clear ! Best answer. Worked for me.

Comment: In my case, for step 4, I opened jdk. In essense, I had this for PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin. javac.exe was not in the jre but in the jdk.

Comment: Works for Me :)

Answer (score 39):

After a long Google, I came to know that javac.exe will be inside **JDK**(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version number)\bin) not inside **JRE** (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin)  **"JRE doesn't come with a compiler. It(JRE) is simply a java runtime environment. What you need is the Java development kit."** in order to use  compiler javac

javac will not work if the path points to  **bin** inside **jre** folder

In order to use javac in cmd , JDK must be installed in your system...

**For javac  path**

**path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin**  this is wrong

**path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version number)\bin**  this is correct

Make sure that "javac.exe" is inside your **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk(version number)\bin"**

Don't get confused with JRE and JDK  both are totally different

if you don't have JDK pls download from this link

https://jdk.java.net/

or

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

reference thread for JDK VS JRE  [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

Answer (score 6):

I know this may not be your specific error, but I once had a leading space in my path and java would work but javac would not.

For what it's worth, I offer the sage advice: "Examine your Path closely".

Answer (score 5):

Okay this can not be the case always but many of us have done this mistake in the past and few out of those are still not aware of it, which is, every time you append a path (any path) of any environment variable, you're likely to hit the space bar right after the "semicolon" (as you normally would, after the "period" while typing in an editor).

This will create a leading space in the path e.g " C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin" and therefore "javac.exe" won't be found by the system.

Answer (score 5):

Try the solutions here: http://techdem.centerkey.com/2009/05/javahome-command-script.html

These are much more robust to change -- like when you upgrade the JDK or JRE, since there is no hard coded path.

The quick solution (if you don't want to read the blog) is

```
C:\>for /d %i in ("\Program Files\Java\jdk*") do set JAVA_HOME=%i
C:\>set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%
```

You can then add these lines to a startup/login script.

Comment: For invoking javac like that I had to use "set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin" (notice the added \bin).

Answer (score 4):

I just had to do this to get this to work on windows 7 64.

Open up a command prompt (cmd.exe) and type:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin
```

Make sure you reopen all running command prompt Windows to get the environment variable updated as well.

Comment: I guess unsetting the classpath is better here. I would not use the CLASSPATH variable, especially not on Windows where it is global and affects multiple JREs...

Answer (score 2):

Change the folder "jdk1.7.0_45" "jdk1_7_0_60" and update the path in Windows environment. Otherwise, the path ignores the dot at the front which stands for hidden file and so the folder is not displayed in PATH strings.

Answer (score 0):

";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin" sometime you may forget to put semicolon on last existing path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem posted in this title. Java would work, but `javac` would not in the Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`).

For me, it was simply that I had placed a space when adding `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin` to the end of my `%PATH%` environment variable.
Remove the space between the `;` and the next file path.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem that java would work but javac would not on a cmd prompt in Windows 8.

The problem occured because I forgot to remove `'>'` at the end of the path name, i.e., it was like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin>
```

where it was suppose to be like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The path will only be set for the administrator account. Therefore it is important to launch command prompt as administrator, if you are not already.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't allow spaces (white space) in between paths in the Path variable. My problem was I had white space in and I believe Windows treated it as a NULL and didn't read my path in for Java.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old question now but my solution wasn't an answer on here so posting it in case anyone else tries all the rest.

In my case, a previous install of the Java JRE (in ProgramData/Oracle/Java) had a path variable at the top of my list of path variables. The contents of that "Oracle" path had a java.exe but not a javac.exe.
I added my full JDK path to the top of the list of path variables, ahead of the "Oracle" one, and it then picked up javac.exe as well as java.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %i in ("\Program Files\Java\jdk*") do set JAVA_HOME=%i
set JAVA_HOME
```

[this](http://blog.centerkey.com/2009/05/javahome-command-script.html) solution worked to me

Comment: I'd suggest to add more annotation to your answer directly instead of just providing a link: the link may get broken. Best regards

Answer (score -3):

When i tried to make the .java to .class the command Javac didnt work. I got it working by going to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin and when i was on that directory I typed Javac.exe C\Test\test.java and it made the class with that tactic. Try that out.

Answer (score -7):

Give it as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin". Remove the backslash it will work

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I can set my path to be nothing but "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\" (with trailing slash) and it still works fine.