# Cannot install xlsx package for R

Tags: java, r, xlsx

Cannot install R package xlsx.

I have previously used the package on other PCs and had no trouble with it whatsoever, but am having difficulty with a new PC. From what I can tell the issue is something to do with Java. Currently tried:

- Downloading Java Development Kit
- Downloading JRE
- Editing environment variables to point to the right Java (for both of the above)
- Running through the R console (both 32 and 64 bit)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Rstudio / R

> install.packages("xlsx")
>   `Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Fred Goktas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
>     There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
>        binary source needs_compilation
>   xlsx  0.5.7  0.6.1             FALSE
>   installing the source package ‘xlsx’
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xlsx_0.6.1.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 315441 bytes (308 KB)
>   downloaded 308 KB
>   * installing *source* package 'xlsx' ...
>   ** package 'xlsx' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** preparing package for lazy loading
>   ** help
>   *** installing help indices
>
>   ** building package indices
>
>   ** installing vignettes
>
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
>   *** arch - i386
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Fred Goktas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   *** arch - x64
>   ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/Fred Goktas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/xlsx'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
> "C:\Users\Fred Goktas\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" 
> C:\Users\FREDGO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYLz0xk/downloaded_packages/xlsx_0.6.1.tar.gz' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘xlsx’ had non-zero exit status

Package should install without any troubles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install rJava for use with 64bit R on a 64 bit Windows computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120270/how-can-i-install-rjava-for-use-with-64bit-r-on-a-64-bit-windows-computer)

Comment: Have you properly installed `rJava` on that machine? These tips might help: https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/

Comment: Do you have the `RJava` package installed and the `JAVA HOME` environment variable set? I suggest that you try the `openxlsx` package if you want to manipulate xlsx files in R. It does not rely on Java.

Comment: Simply try:

    install.packages('openxlsx')

You can achieve many tasks you need `xlsx` for with `openxlsx`, but the latter removes the dependency on Java while providing the same speed.

Comment: If you would like to fully uninstall then clean reinstall R and RStudio, follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/1953250

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have no compelling reason to use `xlsx`, I would suggest you consider [`readxl`](https://readxl.tidyverse.org) because it has no external dependencies.