# rJava Warning Meaning

Tags: r, package

I am trying to compile a package for R that uses `openNLP` which relies on `rJava`.  The compiling fails with this message:

[image]

When I try to load the package in R it says:

```
library(openNLP)
Warning message:
replacing previous import ‘show’ when loading ‘rJava’
```

I can't compile the package as it kills the process because the package fails to load due to this error(I think).  I tried updating Java but that does not fix this issue.

Help please.

R 2.15.0 on a win 7 machine

Here's a screen shot of my Java and R info:
[image]

[image]

Comment: PS I downloaded the latest version of `rJava` and `openNLP` as well.

Comment: I think the problem is related to this: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r)

Comment: I also tried getting rJava directly from Rforge.

Comment: It is failing to install the package "qdap". Is this custom package? I don't see it on cran...

Comment: @Ian Yes this is correct Ian I want to eventually  put it in CRAN.  My apologies for not mentioning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was between a 32 bit windows and a 64 bit java.  I downloaded the 32 bit java and it worked (though I still get a warning)