# Problems loading rJava Package on Win7

Tags: r, windows-7, rjava

I have installed the latest versions of R (2.15.2) and Java (7.11), and through RStudio (0.97.310) I am trying to load the rJava package. It seemed to install properly, but when I call `library(rJava)` I get the following error:

```
 Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: stop("No CurrentVersion entry in '", key, "'! 
 Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.")
 error: object 'key' not found
 Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

The documentation for rJava makes reference to Java 1.5+, so I am wondering if I need to install an ancient version of Java to resolve this problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check out if you need for 64bit or 32.  Your java type and R type need to match.  See: http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

Comment: Which version of java are you sung `system("java -version")`?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate to the question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545458/rjava-warning-meaning but mine was more for compiling the package.  In any event the issue is the same.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I figured it out. Guess I should have read the release notes on the rJava development website. I had installed Java, but not the JDK. Once I installed that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it by downloading and installing Java 64-bit (which you should probably choose if you have a modern computer) from the [Java download site](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).