# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

Tags: r, rjava

So I have tried the previously proposed answer to my question. but I am still having the same error message:
I am trying to load the `rJava` library in R

```
library(rJava) 

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)   
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Lauriane/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':   
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.  
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: may be this can help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661325/unable-to-load-rjava-on-r

Comment: You can check whether your Java architecture is is same as that of the R version you are using. `rJava` needs both of them to be on the same architecture. 32-bit or 64-bit. I had the same problem.

Comment: This may help. It helped for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073113/5238639

Comment: Here's what worked in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417282/5783745

Answer (score 8):

For me the problem was caused because a 32-bit Java version was installed on the system, but I was running 64-bit version of `R`. Installing the 64-bit Java version solved the problem with `rJava` namespace environment. Because I am running a 32-bit browser I had to manually download the 64-bit Java version.

Comment: This worked for me. https://www.java.com/fr/download/manual.jsp then in R Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_251/") ; library(rJava)

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is explained [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2254). Essentially, do `sudo R CMD javareconf` in the terminal and reboot.

Comment: This solve my issue. I install dplyr then cause the issue of rJava.

Comment: This worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem  and, as suggested in previous comments, I manually installed the 64-bit version, selecting it [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp). I only had to restart R. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add one more possible solution, since I tried all of the suggestions listed above (reinstalling Java x64, installing both JDK & JRE, setting JAVA_HOME, `sudo R CMD javareconf` or even `sudo R CMD javareconf -n` seen elsewhere, and more) but none of them worked and I kept getting the following error:

```
> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

There were 2 possible solutions that helped me get through this error:

- Go to the location of your Java installation (in my Mac OS it was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`) where you'll find a folder titled something like "jdk-13.0.1.jdk" (depending on your JDK version). Changing its name to "jdk-11.0.1.jdk" (or whatever is mentioned in your error) should solve your problem.

But maybe even better is to do the following ***instead***:

- Go to the file referenced in the error: `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so`, open it in a text editor (such as TextEdit) and change "jdk-11.0.1.jdk" to "jdk-13.0.1.jdk" (or whatever is the folder referenced in your error and what is actually in your Java folder, respectively).

Either way worked for me but the latter looks a bit cleaner to me.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

From what I've understood this was due to two reasons: a) R being 64-bits and Java being on 32-bits, b) R being installed in D:\Documents and Java being installed in C:\Programmes.

I've solved the issue by:

- Disinstalling all previous versions of Java
- Disinstalling both R and RStudio
- Installing both R, Rstudio and Java in 64 bits in a new folder called D:\Programmes
- For Java I have installed both the JDK and JRE in the same folder
- Setting JAVA_HOME as an environment variable making sure that the environment variable was pointing to bin.