# Scraping a Table from a PDF File

Tags: r, pdf, stringr, pdftools

I am trying to scrape the first table of multiple PDF's that look quite similar. So far I have isolated the page of the table, converted the table to a string and loaded it into `R`. Additionally, I also managed to remove the parts of the table I am not interested in as well as the header since it seemed like it will cause trouble because of the awkward spacing.

```
x <- pdf_text("2010 Table.pdf") # x is the string that I have attached at below
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "Männer\r\n", fixed = T))[1]
x <- unlist(regmatches(x, regexpr("Insgesamt", x), invert = TRUE))[2]
cat(x)

   0 b. unter    2   564.855     356.279 13.019          191.169      128.236          38 14.135 9.682          208.190           386
   2 b. unter    4   300.245     205.375 31.056            96.882      68.185          18  7.032 2.202            94.062          808
   4 b. unter    6   279.717     167.463 10.312            78.783      69.751          33  6.886 1.698          111.252        1.002
   6 b. unter    8   247.614     140.412 22.926            62.535      47.390          88  6.554     919        105.818        1.384
   8 b. unter 10     268.805     144.298 21.682            66.518      48.945         140  6.278     735        123.181        1.326
 10 b. unter 12      393.303     144.576 18.387            65.387      51.705         177  8.500     420        245.470        3.257
 12 b. unter 15      433.705     216.278 13.858            97.828      88.199         432 15.485     476        210.658        6.769
 15 b. unter 18      423.441     224.532     4.804       106.780       94.846      1.116 16.552      434        188.577      10.332
 18 b. unter 20      273.151     156.661     1.426         74.867      67.740      1.260 11.177      191        107.232        9.258
 20 b. unter 25      653.650     389.246     1.330       190.154      156.275      5.086 36.186      215        234.087      30.317
 25 b. unter 30      607.956     408.773            -    189.718      162.837      9.942 46.086      190        166.255      32.928
 30 b. unter 35      501.137     357.262            -    141.724      150.686     19.403 45.196      253        110.461      33.414
 35 b. unter 40      356.800     269.775            -      84.928     127.510     24.572 32.501      264          61.994     25.031
 40 b. unter 50      422.582     348.116            -      70.498     187.365     54.388 35.555      310          41.506     32.960
 50 b. unter 70      368.803     318.168            -      19.958     201.735     70.950 25.001      524          23.373     27.262
 70 b. unter 100     160.051     140.411            -         850     105.534     25.262   8.311     454           9.441     10.199
100 b. unter 150        55.966     50.910           -            -     42.024      5.961   2.541     384           3.336       1.720
150 b. unter 200        11.776     10.977           -            -     10.028         587    252     110              674         125
200 und mehr             9.654       9.146          -            -      8.828         182    104       32             475          33
  Insgesamt ...    6,333.211 4,058.658 138.800 1.538.579 1.817.819               219.635 324.332 19.493       2.046.042     228.511
```

At this point, I thought that the best way to get this into a `data.frame()` was to use `read.table()`, unfortunately, since the spacing in between the columns is so inconsistent I cannot get it to work.

I appreciate any ideas, hints or solutions. 
Thanks!

---

**Data**

```
"Steuerpflichtige 2010 nach Geschlecht, sozialer Stellung und Bruttobezugsstufen\r\n                                                                                                                           Tabelle 2\r\n                                                                          Davon\r\n                                Unselb-                                                                   Pensionisten u.\r\n     Stufen der      Steuer-                                                                     Pers. m. Pensionistinnen Beamte und\r\n                                 ständig              Arbeiter und\r\n    Bruttobezüge    pflichtige                                                 Beamte und         sonst. o. Beamten und Beamtinnen\r\n                                Erwerbs-   Lehrlinge    Arbeite-   Angestellte             VB\r\n   in 1.000 EUR    insgesamt                                                   Beamtinnen         Aktiv- Beamtinnen i. R.    i.R.\r\n                                  tätige                 rinnen\r\n                                                                                                 bezügen\r\n                                                                Insgesamt\r\n   0 b. unter    2   564.855     356.279 13.019          191.169      128.236          38 14.135 9.682          208.190           386\r\n   2 b. unter    4   300.245     205.375 31.056            96.882      68.185          18  7.032 2.202            94.062          808\r\n   4 b. unter    6   279.717     167.463 10.312            78.783      69.751          33  6.886 1.698          111.252        1.002\r\n   6 b. unter    8   247.614     140.412 22.926            62.535      47.390          88  6.554     919        105.818        1.384\r\n   8 b. unter 10     268.805     144.298 21.682            66.518      48.945         140  6.278     735        123.181        1.326\r\n 10 b. unter 12      393.303     144.576 18.387            65.387      51.705         177  8.500     420        245.470        3.257\r\n 12 b. unter 15      433.705     216.278 13.858            97.828      88.199         432 15.485     476        210.658        6.769\r\n 15 b. unter 18      423.441     224.532     4.804       106.780       94.846      1.116 16.552      434        188.577      10.332\r\n 18 b. unter 20      273.151     156.661     1.426         74.867      67.740      1.260 11.177      191        107.232        9.258\r\n 20 b. unter 25      653.650     389.246     1.330       190.154      156.275      5.086 36.186      215        234.087      30.317\r\n 25 b. unter 30      607.956     408.773            -    189.718      162.837      9.942 46.086      190        166.255      32.928\r\n 30 b. unter 35      501.137     357.262            -    141.724      150.686     19.403 45.196      253        110.461      33.414\r\n 35 b. unter 40      356.800     269.775            -      84.928     127.510     24.572 32.501      264          61.994     25.031\r\n 40 b. unter 50      422.582     348.116            -      70.498     187.365     54.388 35.555      310          41.506     32.960\r\n 50 b. unter 70      368.803     318.168            -      19.958     201.735     70.950 25.001      524          23.373     27.262\r\n 70 b. unter 100     160.051     140.411            -         850     105.534     25.262   8.311     454           9.441     10.199\r\n100 b. unter 150        55.966     50.910           -            -     42.024      5.961   2.541     384           3.336       1.720\r\n150 b. unter 200        11.776     10.977           -            -     10.028         587    252     110              674         125\r\n200 und mehr             9.654       9.146          -            -      8.828         182    104       32             475          33\r\n  Insgesamt ...    6,333.211 4,058.658 138.800 1.538.579 1.817.819               219.635 324.332 19.493       2.046.042     228.511\r\n                                                                  Männer\r\n   0 b. unter    2   248.906     160.190     6.586         93.371      48.212          29  5.114 6.878            88.630           86\r\n   2 b. unter    4   125.032       89.536   19.507         44.637      21.775          14  2.271 1.332            35.221          275\r\n   4 b. unter    6      89.016     63.413    5.071         35.777      19.838          22  1.784     921          25.212          391\r\n   6 b. unter    8      82.674     58.262   13.407         29.985      12.776          54  1.506     534          23.882          530\r\n   8 b. unter 10        85.708     56.336   12.730         29.898      11.816         106  1.303     483          28.905          467\r\n 10 b. unter 12      113.358       56.129   13.686         29.542      11.193          69  1.414     225          56.581          648\r\n 12 b. unter 15      151.134       76.371   11.879         45.603      16.424          64  2.189     212          73.581       1.182\r\n 15 b. unter 18      165.399       74.808    4.262         51.314      16.662          77  2.331     162          87.632       2.959\r\n 18 b. unter 20      114.691       56.582    1.327         40.448      12.967         120  1.631       89         54.817       3.292\r\n 20 b. unter 25      333.825     180.786     1.253       132.966       37.908      1.335   7.212     112        137.384      15.655\r\n 25 b. unter 30      368.614     239.655            -    162.373       56.488      4.739 15.925      130        110.753      18.206\r\n 30 b. unter 35      329.970     230.335            -    131.377       68.331     12.250 18.175      202          79.989     19.646\r\n 35 b. unter 40      236.845     178.551            -      80.873      68.707     14.633 14.118      220          43.882     14.412\r\n 40 b. unter 50      280.849     234.429            -      68.109     119.325     31.658 15.089      248          27.331     19.089\r\n 50 b. unter 70      260.231     225.846            -      19.120     152.331     41.375 12.658      362          16.225     18.160\r\n 70 b. unter 100     128.140     112.891            -         802      88.423     18.037   5.277     352           7.340       7.909\r\n100 b. unter 150        47.894     43.663           -            -     36.447      5.003   1.924     289           2.759       1.472\r\n150 b. unter 200        10.380       9.685          -            -      8.888         507    205       85             584         111\r\n200 und mehr             8.813       8.353          -            -      8.081         153     94       25             431          29\r\n  Insgesamt ...    3,181.479 2,155.821      89.708       996.195      816.592    130.245 110.220 12.861         901.139     124.519\r\n                                                                  Frauen\r\n   0 b. unter    2   315.949     196.089     6.433         97.798      80.024           9  9.021   2.804        119.560           300\r\n   2 b. unter    4   175.213     115.839    11.549         52.245      46.410           4  4.761     870          58.841          533\r\n   4 b. unter    6   190.701     104.050     5.241         43.006      49.913          11  5.102     777          86.040          611\r\n   6 b. unter    8   164.940       82.150    9.519         32.550      34.614          34  5.048     385          81.936          854\r\n   8 b. unter 10     183.097       87.962    8.952         36.620      37.129          34  4.975     252          94.276          859\r\n 10 b. unter 12      279.945       88.447    4.701         35.845      40.512         108  7.086     195        188.889        2.609\r\n 12 b. unter 15      282.571     139.907     1.979         52.225      71.775         368 13.296     264        137.077        5.587\r\n 15 b. unter 18      258.042     149.724        542        55.466      78.184      1.039 14.221      272        100.945        7.373\r\n 18 b. unter 20      158.460     100.079          99       34.419      54.773      1.140   9.546     102          52.415       5.966\r\n 20 b. unter 25      319.825     208.460          77       57.188     118.367      3.751 28.974      103          96.703     14.662\r\n 25 b. unter 30      239.342     169.118            -      27.345     106.349      5.203 30.161        60         55.502     14.722\r\n 30 b. unter 35      171.167     126.927            -      10.347      82.355      7.153 27.021        51         30.472     13.768\r\n 35 b. unter 40      119.955       91.224           -       4.055      58.803      9.939 18.383        44         18.112     10.619\r\n 40 b. unter 50      141.733     113.687            -       2.389      68.040     22.730 20.466        62         14.175     13.871\r\n 50 b. unter 70      108.572       92.322           -         838      49.404     29.575 12.343      162           7.148       9.102\r\n 70 b. unter 100        31.911     27.520           -           48     17.111      7.225   3.034     102           2.101       2.290\r\n100 b. unter 150         8.072       7.247          -            -      5.577         958    617       95             577         248\r\n150 b. unter 200         1.396       1.292          -            -      1.140          80     47       25              90          14\r\n200 und mehr                841        793          -            -        747          29     10        7              44           4\r\n  Insgesamt ...    3,151.732 1,902.837      49.092       542.384 1.001.227        89.390 214.112   6.632      1.144.903     103.992\r\n                                                                     38\r\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tabulizer::extract_tables()`. `strsplit` "weird-spaced" columns and `cbind` the snippets.

```
link <- "my.pdf"

library(tabulizer)
ext <- el(extract_tables(link, encoding="UTF-8"))

res <- cbind(ext[, 1:5], do.call(rbind, strsplit(ext[, 6], " ")),
             ext[, 7:12])[, -c(2, 8)]
# store information for dim. names
dim.nm <- list(res[1:20, 1], 
               c("insg", "uns", "lehrl", "arb",
                 "ang", "beam", "VB", "sonst",
                 "pens", "beam.ir"))
# I would divide in a lists here
res <- list(insg=res[1:20, -1],
            mann=res[22:41, -1],
            frau=res[43:62, -1])
# convert to numbers (using gsub() to get rid of separators)
res <- Map(function(x) apply(x, 2, function(i) as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", i))), res)
res <- lapply(res, `dimnames<-`, dim.nm)
head(res$insg)
#                  insg    uns lehrl    arb    ang beam    VB sonst   pens beam.ir
# 0 b. unter 2   564855 356279 13019 191169 128236   38 14135  9682 208190     386
# 2 b. unter 4   300245 205375 31056  96882  68185   18  7032  2202  94062     808
# 4 b. unter 6   279717 167463 10312  78783  69751   33  6886  1698 111252    1002
# 6 b. unter 8   247614 140412 22926  62535  47390   88  6554   919 105818    1384
# 8 b. unter 10  268805 144298 21682  66518  48945  140  6278   735 123181    1326
# 10 b. unter 12 393303 144576 18387  65387  51705  177  8500   420 245470    3257
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf I am currently struggling to install the `tabulizer` package, which `R` version are you running?

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R I'm using `0.2.2`. Try the installation procedure illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147228/6574038).

Comment: When calling `library(rJava)`  I get the error: `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
  Aufruf: fun(libname, pkgname)
  Fehler: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry` Any chance you know what JAVA_HOME refers to here ?

Comment: Hmm, have you [java installed](https://www.java.com/de/download/)?

Comment: Yes, I just did, still getting the same error. I think I may have to manually set the directory.

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R I remember there was an issue, once solved you don't need to worry anymore though. Have you followed that "specific order"`? Maybe try uninstall and install again.

Comment: Or consult this solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42258473/6574038

Comment: your code doesn't work for me (cbind dimensions dont match), however, I think to have this package now installed with your help I can manage doing the remaining stuff. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome @Base_R_Best_R ! I freshly OCRed your .png into a readable .pdf, maybe this is the difference.