# Initiating h2o in RStudio on MacOSX; Java issue

Tags: java, jvm, rstudio, h2o, macos-high-sierra

I'm at a loss as to why this seems so challenging, but isn't that what always separates us into two piles.

Here's what I have;

```
    - Today April 27th 2019
    - MacOSX - High Sierra version 10.13.6
    -- older MacBook Air 2010 build
    - RStudio - Version 1.1.453
    - h2o downloaded from within RStudio
    -- from http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R/src/contrib/h2o_3.24.0.2.tar.gz
    -- installed in RStudio and library active
```

attempting to run

```
h2o.init()

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
Error in .h2o.startJar(ip = ip, port = port, name = name, nthreads = nthreads,  : 
  Your java is not supported: java version "1.6.0_65"
Please download the latest Java SE JDK 8 from the following URL:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

Slightly more elaborate version provides exact same result

```
h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, name = NA_character_,
         startH2O = TRUE, forceDL = FALSE, enable_assertions = TRUE,
         license = NULL, nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = NULL,
         min_mem_size = NULL, ice_root = tempdir(), log_dir = NA_character_,
         log_level = NA_character_, strict_version_check = TRUE,
         proxy = NA_character_, https = FALSE, insecure = FALSE,
         username = NA_character_, password = NA_character_,
         cookies = NA_character_, context_path = NA_character_,
         ignore_config = FALSE, extra_classpath = NULL,
         jvm_custom_args = NULL, bind_to_localhost = TRUE)
```

from terminal

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.38.0.13-CA-macosx) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.38.0.13-CA-macosx) (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

On surface it seems that h2o and the Terminal are thinking two different version of Java are the current version.

Using SDKMAN in terminal

```
sdk list java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     13.ea.18-open       10.0.2-zulu         1.0.0-rc-15-grl                    
     12.0.1-sapmchn      10.0.2-open         1.0.0-rc-14-grl                    
     12.0.1-zulu         9.0.7-zulu                                             
     12.0.1-open         9.0.4-open                                             
     12.0.1.j9-adpt  > * 8.0.212-zulu                                           
     12.0.1.hs-adpt      8.0.212-amzn                                           
     12.0.1-librca       8.0.212.j9-adpt                                        
     11.0.3-sapmchn      8.0.212.hs-adpt                                        
     11.0.3-zulu         8.0.212-librca                                         
     11.0.3-amzn         8.0.202-zulu                                           
     11.0.3.j9-adpt      8.0.202-amzn                                           
     11.0.3.hs-adpt      8.0.202-zulufx                                         
     11.0.3-librca       7.0.222-zulu                                           
     11.0.2-open         7.0.181-zulu                                           
     11.0.2-zulufx       1.0.0-rc-16-grl                                        

================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
```

Sadly, I've tried so many things from various threads that it's probably not even worth going into them. Basically after countless changes, downloads, restarts, etc.... none of them have changed the end result when trying to initiate h2o in RStudio.

Thoughts?

Comment: From inside the R session try manually setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable such that $JAVA_HOME/bin/java is the java8 that you want H2O to use.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to be able to find any instruction on setting JAVA_HOME in the R session.

Comment: See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/Sys.setenv. There's good discussion on a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661325/unable-to-load-rjava-on-r.

Comment: You can set the environmental variable in R by Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='path/to/java').

Comment: '> Sys.setenv(Java_home="\\Library\\Java\\JavaVirtualMachines\\jdk1.8.0_212")
> Sys.getenv("Java_home")
[1] "\\Library\\Java\\JavaVirtualMachines\\jdk1.8.0_212"
> 
> h2o.init()

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
Error in .h2o.startJar(ip = ip, port = port, name = name, nthreads = nthreads,  : 
  Your java is not supported: java version "1.6.0_65"
Please download the latest Java SE JDK 8 from the following URL:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html' Still not working, I tried double slashes both / and \ same error each time.

Comment: As a next step, please confirm the `JAVA_HOME` path contains a bin folder. What is the terminal output of `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212`? Note that your goal is to set `JAVA_HOME` such that `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` points to an existing folder.