# adding a new column derived from a different table without using the "merge" function

Tags: r

Suppose these two tables - A and B

table A is

```
id v1  
1  10
3  20
5  20
6  15
```

table B is

```
id v2  
1  200
2  300
3  200
4  250
5  190
6  290
```

I want to add "v2" of B to A with the same "id" as follows:

table A should be

```
id v1 v2
1  10 200
3  20 200
5  20 190
6  15 290
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Any particular reason for not using "merge"? Just curious

Comment: My table is a sequence object created by TraMineR. When I merged my table with a regular data frame, I found my sequence table is corrupted if my understanding is correct. So I am trying to simply add a new column .

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` which is based on X[Y] syntax:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
setkey(dt1, "id")
setkey(dt2, "id")
> dt2[dt1]

#    id  v2 v1
# 1:  1 200 10
# 2:  3 200 20
# 3:  5 190 20
# 4:  6 290 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT dat.*,dat1.v2
       FROM dat,dat1
       WHERE dat.id = dat1.id')
  id v1  v2
1  1 10 200
2  3 20 200
3  5 20 190
4  6 15 290
```

But using `merge` we get the same result

```
merge(dat,dat1)
  id v1  v2
1  1 10 200
2  3 20 200
3  5 20 190
4  6 15 290
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an environment lookup via:

```
library(qdap)

A$v2 <- lookup(A$id, B)
A

> A
  id v1  v2
1  1 10 200
2  3 20 200
3  5 20 190
4  6 15 290
```

This is pretty fast on large data sets.

Comment: I have an error to install qdap, such as **Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: stop("No CurrentVersion entry in '", key, "'! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.")
  error: object 'key' not found
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘qdap’** Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes you have a different version of R and java.  Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545458/rjava-warning-meaning/10859487#10859487 where I explain this in more detail.

Comment: This may also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631494/problems-loading-rjava-package-on-win7#comment20438086_14631494  When you get it can you state what you did for other users?