# Cannot load libraries in R, LoadLibrary failure: access denied

Tags: r, dplyr, package

I have been running scripts as usual, and suddenly have encountered an error when running:

```
library(dplyr)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '//universitySystem/Documents/R/win-
library/3.2/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Access is denied.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’
```

I have been looking at various help pages e.g.
[Unable to load any package in R (unable to load shared object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034542/unable-to-load-any-package-in-r-unable-to-load-shared-object)

But I can't seem to get anything to work, and I don't really understand what the error means.

Now when I go to load any package in R, I get a similar error.

I am using R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) on platform x86_64-w64-mingw32, on a university computer where I have some admin rights.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Pretty desperate as I need to hand in my thesis soon, and now none of my scripts work.

Comment: The path mentioned there is weird. It seems your R library is installed on a shared drive in your University network. Are you online and connected to that network? And why is the R library not installed locally?

Comment: Hi Konrad, the "universitySystem" part I have anonymised but does represent a shared university driver. I am online and connected to that network, but I normally work out of my local drive. When I started learning R it must have saved it there automatically, but I am not sure what to do. I found the following in my local drive: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.5/library.....