# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arrow’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...): unable to load shared object

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I have uploaded R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18). After installing the arrow package when I require it I got the message below, and also I have installed Rtoos 4.0 related to R version.

Error message:

```
> library(arrow)
```

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arrow’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/el_ki/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/arrow/libs/x64/arrow.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  Error en una rutina de inicialización de biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (DLL).

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tidyselect_1.1.2  bit_4.0.4         compiler_4.1.0    magrittr_2.0.3    assertthat_0.2.1  R6_2.5.1
[7] cli_3.3.0         tools_4.1.0       glue_1.6.2        rstudioapi_0.13   bit64_4.0.5       vctrs_0.4.1
[13] data.table_1.14.2 rlang_1.0.4       purrr_0.3.4

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058317/5783745

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but an idea is to navigate to this file `C:/Users/el_ki/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/arrow/libs/x64/arrow.dll` right click, and see if you can change its permissions

Comment: @stevec I changed permissions, but the issue was not solved.

Comment: I haven't had this particular issue before. But I've seem similar ones. TBH I would first try re installing the package `install.packages("arrow", dependencies=TRUE)`, closing and reopening RStudio. If that doesn't work, I'd try reinstalling R and RStudio, selecting all the defaults. That has occasionally solved similar problems for me in the past.

Comment: @stevec I've followed the procedure showed in this post to uninstall R, Rstudio and Rtools 4.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204017/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-with-all-packages-settings-and-everything-else , but the issue was not solved yet.