# Javac is not found

Tags: java, windows-8, compilation, javac

I'm running Windows 8 and I can not get javac to work.

I have set my PATH in environmental variables to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin`

I have tried both with and without ';' but to no avail.

I recently had this issue on my desktop and adding ; worked but it's not in this case.

I have made sure that javac does exist in the bin too.

Any suggestions on fixes would be greatly appreciated.

EDITS
echo %PATH% gives:

```
C:\Users\Arktri\Desktop>echo %PATH%

C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

And the exact error is: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: can you start a shell, type `echo %PATH%` and post results?

Comment: What is the error that you see?  Saying "I can not get [it] to work" doesn't tell us anything about the problem.

Comment: The double semicolons might be a problem.

Comment: Do you have an extra space in you path? I can see: Pr ogram Files there...

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As far as I can see you have the `JRE` in your `PATH`, but not the `JDK`.

From a command prompt try this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin
```

Then try `javac` again - if this works you'll need to permanently modify your environment variables to have `PATH` include the `JDK` too.

Comment: Could you include here the information how to do it permanently?

Comment: I should have when I first posted this answer, but I suggest taking a look at @user4611364 answer below. Doing it that way will set it permanently (assuming you're using windows)

Answer (score 29):

1. Go to my computer;
2. Right click properties;
3. Go to advanced system settings;
4. Go to environment variables;
5. In user variables for user click on new(top new button, not on system variables);
6. Set variable name as: `Path`
7. Set the value of that variable to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76\bin`
8. Click ok;
9. Click ok;
10. Click ok.

Now you're set. Type `javac` in cmd. All javac options will be displayed.

**EDIT:** As @MediaMaker pointed out, after completing the above steps, you need to open a new command prompt for it to work.

Comment: note that if you already have a cmd open and try to use that, it won't seem to work. You'll need to open a fresh cmd.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way: search for javac.exe in windows search bar. Then copy and paste the entire folder name and add it into the environmental variables path in advanced system settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searched many answers that suggest me to type in cmd:

```
set path = "%path%;c:program files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin"
```

but this is WRONG!

**the right solution** is that you leave "set" and just type

```
path = %path%;c:program files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

*P/s: of course you have to replace "jdk1.7.0" folder by your current java version folder. This works well on win 7 32bit, but I think it also works on win 8 - try it!*

Answer (score 0):

Start off by opening a cmd.exe session, changing directory to the "program files" directory that has the javac.exe executable and running .\javac.exe.

If that doesn't work, reinstall java.  If that works, odds are you will find (in doing that task) that you've installed a 64 bit `javac.exe`, or a slightly different release number of `javac.exe`, or in a different drive, etc. and selecting the right entry in your path will become child's play.

Only use the semicolon *between* directories in the PATH environment variable, and remember that in *some* systems, you need to log out and log back in before the new environment variable is accessible to *all* environments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have jdk1.7.0_17 in your PATH - check again.
There is only JRE which may not contain 'javac' compiler.

Besides it is best to set JAVA_HOME variable, and then include it in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

do this:
1. run CMD (WIN+R then type in CMD)
2. Type this:

set PATH=%PATH%; java installation path\bin

Replace "java installation path" with the directory JDK is installed in, such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Java. Be sure to add the \bin after the JDK directory, because this points to "javac" and "java" (BIN stands for "binaries")

This way, you can run the Java compiler from anywhere. It is impossible to CD to the JDK directory because it has a space in Program Files, and DOS will not let you CD to these directories.

Answer (score 0):

**Just type** enviormental vairables in start menu, and you will see

Edit the system enviormental...,

**click enviromental variables**

**click** in user vairables list:

Path **(ONCE)**

Click **New**

**Copy & Paste** You're Bin directory for the jdk.

e.g.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin

**Hit Enter**

**Open New CMD**

**Type** 'javac'