# When I build solution in Xamarin I see the error: “javac.exe” exited with code 3

Tags: java, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a new project and try to build , but I have this two errors:
“javac.exe” exited with code 3.
And MSB6006:“javac.exe” exited with code 3.
What I have to do to fix it?

File with diagnostic build:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iuNr405Yc8cH7pMg4FixpObCv20Hl_vx/view?usp=sharing

Git: https://github.com/Splinterggg/Repository
The output window is:

```
1>javac: file not found: 
C:\Users\РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC0D4.tmp (The 
system cannot find the path specified)
1>MSB6006: "javac.exe" exited with code 3.
1>Done building project "App1.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>Deployment failed to my_device_1.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: please add a diagnostic build output about this issue. (As a file attachment or gist link), that would be really appreciated!

Comment: Here it is @JessieZhang  
       
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iuNr405Yc8cH7pMg4FixpObCv20Hl_vx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We couldn't see much useful information form the log,  could you please post a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: Sorry,it's new for me.How can I make it ?

Comment: You can try to upload your code to GitHub,and share the link here.

Comment: Here : https://github.com/Splinterggg/Repository

Comment: Well, the demo you post is worked properly in my computer. It should be relative to the development environment of your computer.You can try to check the setting  of android jdk and sdk first, for more details,you can check:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-sdk-location?tabs=windows

Answer (score -1):

I see problems with the java SDK path, that is because *javac* it's not found, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15576035/5373838) response for java SDK path and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) for Android environment variables.

Regards!

Comment: I made what you say , but it don't hepl