# "Missing" jni.h File Causes JPostal Build to Fail

Tags: java, c, gradle, gcc, msys2

I'm trying [to build JPostal](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal#building-jpostal) but I get the following error after issuing the command `./gradlew assemble`:

```
checking for gcj... no
checking for guavac... no
checking for jikes... no
checking for javac... javac
checking if javac works... yes
checking for C:\x\Java\jdk1.8.0_191/include/jni.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBPOSTAL... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/main/c/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

---

```
Making install in src/main/c
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/x/ProgramFiles/JPostal/src/main/c'
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../..     -g -O2 -IC:\x\Java\jdk1.8.0_191/include -MT libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.Tpo -c -o libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.lo `test -f 'jpostal_AddressParser.c' || echo './'`jpostal_AddressParser.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -g -O2 -IC:xJavajdk1.8.0_191/include -MT libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.Tpo -c jpostal_AddressParser.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.o
jpostal_AddressParser.c:1:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <jni.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:473: libjpostal_parser_la-jpostal_AddressParser.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/x/ProgramFiles/JPostal/src/main/c'
make: *** [Makefile:404: install-recursive] Error 1
:buildJniLib FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildJniLib'.
> Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 58.914 secs
```

I installed LibPostal exactly as described [here](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) so why are the file `jni.h`, `gcj`, `guavac` and `jikes` libs missing?

I looked at GitHub and I didn't see any [open issues](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues) addressing this question.

**UPDATE 1**:

In the screenshot below you can see that the `jni.h' file is clearly present in` /include/` folder:

[image]

Comment: `-IC:xJavajdk1.8.0_191/include` The include paths look odd/wrong.

Comment: Does this address your issue? https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/14#issuecomment-290187248

Comment: @ErinParkinson I tried executing `export JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS="C:\x\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\include"` prior to `./gradlew assemble`  but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Perhaps there's a way to update the `autoconf macro` with the above path as suggested in [this link](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/14#issuecomment-290217802)?

Comment: @kaylum I copy/pasted that text from the MSYS2 window. I don't know why it looks like that. Do you have any idea why the path is being corrupted like that?

Comment: You could try [this fork](https://github.com/pontusvision/pontus-jpostal) of jpostal which provides [Windows 64-bit DLLs](https://github.com/pontusvision/pontus-jpostal/tree/master/src/main/resources/lib/win-amd64).

Comment: just to prevent frustration with folder separators and escape character and as a really wild guess: use only / instead of \ as the latter one might be needed to be escaped by another \. Windows will recognize both as folder separators equally.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks!! The build was successful but I don't see the `.so/.jniLib` files under `src/main/jniLibs` (or anywhere) as stated in the [guide](https://github.com/pontusvision/pontus-jpostal#usage-in-a-java-project). Do you have any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: @Olivier This line:     `NativeLoader.loadLibrary("postal"); // Load native library at runtime` causes a NPE. I think it's because the `.so/.jniLib` files were not generated?

Comment: Why would you need a .so or .jniLib? You're on Windows, right?

Comment: @Olivier Yes, I'm on Windows. I guess `.jniLib` is only for Mac? I was able to generate `.dll` files under: `C:\x\ProgramFiles\JPostal\src\main\resources\lib\win-amd64` - how do I get `JPostal` to load the appropriate libraries in Windows? Thanks