# Problems when trying to load a package in R due to rJava

Tags: r, rjava, r-xlsx

When I type `require(xlsx)` in order to load the package `xlsx` in R, the following messages is shown:

```
> require(xlsx)
Loading required package: xlsx
Loading required package: xlsxjars
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded’
```

I've also tried to load the `rJava` package manually but got this error message:

```
require(rJava)
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Try to install `rJava` ...Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r/7604469#7604469)

Comment: Which platform? If Windows then [this](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/) may be helpful.

Comment: also, your problem allow you to first saving your .xlsx file to a csv and then using read.csv, rather than trying to read in the .xlsx file

Comment: If the last listed answer (16 votes at this point) fixed it for you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I ran into this issue too, but diverted it by using Hadley Wickham's `readxl` package.  More discussion about here - [cannot install libraryxlsx in r and look for an alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209152/cannot-install-libraryxlsx-in-r-and-look-for-an-alternative)

Answer (score 149):

The reason is probably linked to the fact you are using a **64-bit** OS and R version but do not have Java installed with the same architecture.
What you have to do is to download Java 64-bit from this page: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

After that just try to reload the `xlsx` package. You shouldn't need to re-start R or if it does not work restart once.

Comment: (+1) I'm not sure if R's message *completely* points to this as the problem, but it was the case for me! To be sure, you can check. If you are running 64 bit OS, and 64 bit R, run the command line and try `java -d64 version`. If you have working 64 bit Java, it could be a system path problem.

Comment: Did you mean `java -d64 -version`?

Comment: If you're running a Mac with an M1 pro chip, this is a problem whose resolution remains a work in progress as of Dec 2022 :  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9543 (scroll to bottom)

Comment: install JAVA 64-bit! Very good, straight to the point. Saved my day!

Answer (score 10):

Its because either one of the Java versions(32 bit/64 bit) is missing from your computer. Try installing both the Jdks and run the code.
After installing the Jdks open R and type the code

```
system("java -version")
```

This will give you the version of Jdk installed. Then try loading the rJava package. This worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem what worked for me was to set JAVA_HOME. I tired it first in R:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/")
```

And when it actually worked I set it in

System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

by adding a new System variable. I then restarted R/RStudio and everything worked.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue. It is caused due the dependent package 'rJava'. This problem can be overcome by re-directing the R to use a different `JAVA_HOME`.

```
if(Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!=""){
    Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")
}
library(rJava)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This did work, but how could it be made permanent? This clearly is just a bandaid, a good one nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative package that you can use is **[`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf)**. This package doesn't require external dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

If you have this error in RStudio, use [Lauren's environmental code above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985724/6461462) and change your R version to the 32 bit version in Tools, Global Options. There should be both 32bit and 64bit R options if you have a newer version. This will require a restart of R, and limit your memory options. Installing the 64 bit version of the jre won't be required though.

Answer (score 1):

For reading/writing excel files, you can use :

- `readxl` package for reading and `writexl` package for writing
- `openxlsx` package for reading and writing

With `xlsx` and `XLConnect` (which use rjava) you will face memory errors if you have large files

Comment: Unfortunately some excel files can only be opened with ```XLConnect```. Context: I work with a lot of excel files from data sources all over the world. My go to packages are ```readxl``` for reading and ```openxlsx``` for writing

Answer (score 1):

For me, I simply needed to make sure the Java was 64-bit (to match R).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417282/5783745) how I downloaded and installed 64-bit Java:

1. Go to: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
2. Click on "Windows Offline (64-bit)"
3. Install it (you may need to find the file that downloaded and double click it, or it may automatically install)
4. Close and reopen your R/RStudio session
5. Everything will work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue with macOS, there is no easy way here: ( Especially, when you want to use R3.4. I have been there already.

[R 3.4, rJava, macOS and even more mess](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718)

For R3.3 it's a little bit easier (R3.3 was compiled using different compiler).

[R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)