# Cannot install library(xlsx) in R and look for an alternative

Tags: r, xlsx, rjava

I use R version 3.0.3. I was not able to install library(xlsx). Error message:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':

LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I then tried to install `rjava` on its own. Got the error message below:

> library("rJava", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library")
> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
> call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
> error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Is there another way to load excel file in R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing .xlsx file into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049272/importing-xlsx-file-into-r)

Comment: Have a look at this blog post on `rJava` http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/  Make sure you have the right version of java.

Comment: May be it's time to test the new openxlsx package which doens't rely on Java http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html

Comment: @dickoa Nice find Didn't know this existed. +1

Comment: @dickoa `package ‘openxlsx’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)` :( :( :(

Comment: You should only have gotten that message if your repository were incomplete ( or you were on a Mac), So please provide more details about he code you are using and your setup.

Comment: @TylerRinker I think this package is new, I'm really happy to have a decent cpp based solution to xlsx IO.

Comment: This will not solve this specific issue, but perhaps you might want to use readxl: https://github.com/hadley/readxl . It has no external dependencies.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Install 64-bit version of Java. Here is the [download link of Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).
2. Re-install `rJava`.
3. Manually set the directory of your Java location by setting it before loading the library

   `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7") # for 64-bit version`
   `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7") # for 32-bit version`
   `library(rJava)`

Source: [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/)

Answer (score 9):

This problem is generally caused by x86 vs x64 bit differences between the R session and the install Java edition. By default Java installs the x86 version and you have to search for the x64 version. if you look at the version of Java you have installed and then open your R session to the same if your using R studio you can click on **`Tools.GlobalOptions`** and then select the version you need.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For mac user, installing Java for OS X 2014-001 works for me
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

Comment: Nothing changed for me after I installed this.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 Pro users 64 bit OS, use

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_144")
```

Answer (score 0):

install.packages("openxlsx")     try to install OPENXLSX instead of XLSX package. Now, the required library will work properly.      library(openxlsx)

Answer (score -1):

For MAC OS X follow these steps in order:

1. Use this command in the Terminal: sudo R CMD javareconf
2. Restart BaseR and RStudio...
3. in RStudio console: install.packages("xlConnect")
4. in RStudio console: library(xlConnect)
5. in RStudio console: library(xlsx)

Problem solved!