# Using write_xlsx in R

Tags: r, writexl

I'm using the write_xlsx command to export data from R to excel,

Here is the data frame that I have,

```
 >df
     X1
 A   76
 B   78
 C   10
```

Using ,

```
write_xlsx(df, "../mydata.xlsx")
```

gives the following output in excel,

```
 >df

1  76
2  78
3  10
```

The column names appear in the xlsx file but the index of each row isn't printed.
Is there any way to print the row index in the excel file?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `writexl::write_xlsx()` as that's the only package that I found with a search. Doesn't look like there's an option to include row names in that one. You have two options: include the row names as a column in the data (preferred), or use a different package, e.g. `openxlsx::write.xlsx(head(mtcars), "test.xlsx", row.names = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below function with argument  `row.names = TRUE`

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df, "../mydata.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Gronowski Could you please which library has to be used for write.xlsx2? I'm trying to install xlsx package via `install.packages("xlsx")` .I get this error though `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
`

Comment: It is in xlsx library. Link
[link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.1/topics/write.xlsx)

Comment: My mistake you could also use normal write.xlsx with argument row.names= TRUE

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the link and tried installing. But there seems to be a problem in accessing the library(xlsx) `Error`: `.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:`

Comment: @Natasha that error is probably because you are using 64 bit R with 32 bit Java (and **xlsx** depends on Java). Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735108/r-error-onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava

Comment: Maybe this will help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209152/cannot-install-libraryxlsx-in-r-and-look-for-an-alternative)

Comment: If you want to use the `xlsx` package make sure your bits line up with R and Java. I would uninstall Java, and the r packages xlsx, rjava, and xlsxjars. I would then install java and then xlsx (other packages will install when you install xlsx)

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Thanks a ton!! That solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use the `write_xlsx()` function (from the `writexl` package), then you can simply make the row names into the first column of the data frame with the `cbind()` function:

```
mtcars1 <- cbind(" "=rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
writexl::write_xlsx(mtcars1, "mtcars1.xlsx")
```

I've used `" "=` so the header of column A will appear blank (it will be a space). It can be easily swapped to some other name (e.g., `Model=`) if desired.

If you have a list of data frames, this can be easily adapted to create a multiple sheet file:

```
mtcars2 <- list(Sheet1=mtcars[1:5, ], Sheet2=mtcars[6:10, ])
mtcars2_1 <- lapply(mtcars2, function(x) cbind(" "=rownames(x), x))
writexl::write_xlsx(mtcars2_1, "mtcars2.xlsx")
```

Comment: I've added this answer as it uses the package used in the question. It is also an option that doesn't require java. The `write.xlsx()` function from the `openxlsx` package is probably the most universally applicable solution though.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as this does not change the package.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the best function for this is `write.xlsx()` from the `openxlsx` package. `rowNames=TRUE` or `row.names=TRUE` writes row names to column A.

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(mtcars, "mtcars.xlsx", rowNames=TRUE)
```

It works for a list of data frames too. Sheet names match the names of the objects in the list (e.g., first_sheet and second_sheet).

```
mtcars2 <- list(first_sheet=mtcars[1:5, ], second_sheet=mtcars[6:10, ])
openxlsx::write.xlsx(mtcars2, "mtcars2.xlsx", rowNames=TRUE)
```

Comment: This option is powerful (freeze panes, header styles, etc.), easy, and doesn't require java, so may be the best solution in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The question is for **write_xl** function which belongs to **writexl** library.
This library has no java dependency and works very fast, my favourite library for writing into excel. Also about the memory usage, it's far better than the others.

Imho, the best solution is using the built-in base R codes rather than an excel library.
So, adding a rowindex column to the data file is a better way:

```
df$rowindex <- as.numeric(rownames(df))
df <- df[,c("rowindex","X1")]  #to fix the column order
```

Additional info about **write_xl**
To provide a name to the sheet:

```
write_xlsx( list( name_of_the_sheet = df ), name_of_the_file )
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize!

It can be used (not a very elegant solution, but works):

```r
mtcars1<-data.frame(rownames(mtcars),mtcars)
```

mtcars1 has one additional column (the first one) formed by the row names
of mtcars, and the same content of mtcars from the 2nd column to the 5th.

```r
write_xlsx(mtcars1,"mtcars1.xlsx")

> dim(mtcars)
[1] 32 11

> dim(mtcars1)
[1] 32 12
```

Important first to

```r
install.packages("writexl")
library(writexl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dariober has an easy two-line solution here: https://www.biostars.org/p/469010/

> It appears write_xlsx doesn't have a parameter row.names. Why don't
> you just add a column for row names to the dataframe dd before writing
> it? Like:

```
dd$row_names <- rownames(dd) 
dd <- dd[, c(ncol(dd), 1:(ncol(dd)-1))] # Make row_names first column
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add column names to df, using colnames("name_col1","name_col2", etc)
before using write_xlsx.

Comment: I don't this your answer addresses the question about how to include the data.frame's row.names in the excel output..