# R on Windows 10, rcmdr 'hasjava' error

Tags: java, r

I am trying to run biodiversity r in r studio with the biodiversity rgui which links up to the rcmdr. I have tried every help forum to find an answer but come up with nothing. I reinstalled R, R studio, updated all packages, installed rjava and javagd and still it refuses to work. I am at wits end!!! I cannot find anything about 'hasjava' and I have updated and installed java already.

Below is copy pasted from the console.

```
Restarting R session...

> library("BiodiversityR", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Loading required package: tcltk
Loading required package: vegan
Loading required package: permute
Loading required package: lattice
This is vegan 2.3-0
BiodiversityR 2.5-3: use function 'BiodiversityRGUI()' to launch the BiodiversityR Graphical User Interface

> library("rJava", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
> BiodiversityRGUI()
Sourced: BiodiversityGUI.R 
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'Rcmdr', details:
  call: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
  error: could not find function "hasJava"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcmdr'
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23742530/1465387) has some similar errors. Do any of its answers help you?

Comment: Tried everything on the post, nothing helps, I am running on windows, I think that is the problem. Have 72 hours to figure out a solution or simply not publish what should be awesome results. Anyone to help??? Please ASAP

Comment: Have you tried installing [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)? Have you ever got this to run before? What does `system("java -version")` give you? There are a few things you could add to what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing directly to do with Windows or with Java.

The **Rcmdr** package no longer uses Java, and the function `hasJava()`, which was defined in and exported by the **Rcmdr**, no longer exists. Apparently **BioDiversityR** uses this function and needs to be updated appropriately.

You might report your problem directly to the maintainer of **BioDiversityR**.

I hope this help,
 John