# rJava libraries fine as a package dependency locally, but not from Git repository

Tags: java, r, git, rjava

I have a package that uses "xlsx" as a dependency, and the package installs libraries fine if I do it from a local file. `library(packagename)` works fine, and so do `library(xlsx)` and `library(rJava)`. We have just begun the process of implementing some badly needed version control, but, when trying to install the same package from a git repository, I get the following error:

```
devtools::install_git(path)
```

...

```
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error : package 'xlsx' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
```

I also tried having `rJava` under `Depends:` in the `DESCRIPTION` listed before `xlsx`, and got the same error.

It seems other people have had the same error loading rJava, so I tried some of those suggestions ([Problems when trying to load a package in R due to rJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376939/problems-when-trying-to-load-a-package-in-r-due-to-rjava)).

System info:

```
> Sys.info()[c("sysname", "release", "version", "machine")]
         sysname              release              version              machine 
       "Windows" "Server >= 2012 x64"         "build 9200"             "x86-64"
```

I've checked, and I'm definitely using 64-bit R

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

And it appears that the Java version is also 64-bit.

```
> system("java -version")
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I've also checked "JAVA_HOME"

```
> Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
[1] ""
> Sys.getenv("JAVA")
[1] ""
```

I'm not sure why the package would work fine as a dependency in a local version of the package but not when installing from a repository. I know we could just add a library(xlsx) to all of our scripts to force solve this issue, but it would be nice to understand what is causing this issue.