# Import specific sheets and specific rows and specific columns from Excel file from readxl package in R

Tags: r

I have a excel file(both xls and xlsx format) with multiple sheets. I have installed readxl package in R. I tried with the below code to import specific sheets, specific rows to columns but getting the error

```
 install.packages("readxl")
 library("readxl")
 sam1 <- read_excel("File1","Sheet1",rowIndex = 6:8,colIndex = 1:13)
```

Error in read_excel("File1", "Sheet1", rowIndex = 6:8,  : 
  unused arguments (rowIndex = 6:8, colIndex = 1:13)

Can we solve this?

Comment: Are ``rowIndex`` and ``colIndex`` even arguments in the ``readxl::read_excel()`` function? Couldn't you use the ``range`` argument to choose the cells you want? Something like : ``read_excel("File1","Sheet1", range = cell_rows(102:151))`` you can also use it for cols with ``range = cell_cols("B:D"))``

Comment: I think you are mistaking the ``readxl`` package for the ``xlsx`` package. The ``xlsx`` package is the one having ``rowIndex`` and ``colIndex`` argument in its function.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably mistaking the `readxl` package with the `xlsx` package. Both of them have a `read_xlsx()` function with different arguments tho.

The result you want can be achieve with the `xlsx` package. You simply have to install the package :

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library("xlsx")
sam1 <- read_excel("File1", "Sheet1", rowIndex = 6:8, colIndex = 1:13)
```

or

```
sam1 <- xlsx::read_excel("File1", "Sheet1", rowIndex = 6:8, colIndex = 1:13)
```

Comment: Not possible i tried I get error like Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

Comment: Yes that is probably a problem with your java version (example Windows 64-bit and Java 64-bit). You could also try to install ``rJava``  You can't run the ``readxl`` package to run a function from the ``xlsx`` package so you should go take a look here to fix your java problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376939/problems-when-trying-to-load-a-package-in-r-due-to-rjava and then try to install the ``xlsx`` package. Otherwise you can use ``readxl::read_excel()`` and give a try to the ``range`` argument.