# I want to add a new sheet and avoid replacing the existing sheet in excel while using the writexl package in R

Tags: r, excel, writexl

I am using writexl package in R to export data frames to excel sheet.

```
library(writexl)
```

However when I use the following code the new data frame (resordered2) replaces the existing excel sheet instead of exporting into the new sheet (Sheet2) as specified in the code.

```
write_xlsx( list (Sheet2 = resordered2), "C:\\Users\\Bharath\\Desktop\\fastqc\\write.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
```

The only way I can see around this issue to create all the date frames at once and list them all under the *list* argument.

I preferably want to work on one data frame after the other. Is there a way to avoid overwriting the existing sheet and adding a new sheet to the excel file using the write_xlsx function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another sheet to an existing .xlsx file you can do it by using the function `write.xlsx` of the library xlsx. Specifying the name of the new sheet in the parameter `sheetName` and setting the parameter `append=TRUE`.

For example:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(data, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="newsheet", append=TRUE)
```

**Update:** since you have problems with xlsx, you can try to use the library openxlsx like this

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "newsheet_1")
writeData(wb, sheet = "newsheet", data_1)

addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "newsheet_2")
writeData(wb, sheet = "newsheet_2", data_2)

saveWorkbook(wb, "filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: It seems my system needs java to load xlsx.  Please see the error below.                                                                                     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 4.1.2

Comment: I updated the answer using another library that maybe it doesn't cause you problems. Otherwise, I suggest you to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376939/problems-when-trying-to-load-a-package-in-r-due-to-rjava