# RJava and XLConnect in RStudio not loading

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava, xlconnect

First the tech specs of what I am using:

```
RStudio 0.98.983
R 3.1.1 (64 Bit)
Windows 8.1
```

When trying to load XLConnect I receive the following error

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: fun(libname, pkgname)

 error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnect’
```

When trying to load RJava I receive the following error

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

I've checked to make sure the newest updates are installed from CRAN.  However I am out of ideas and new to R.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I have Googled this issue for other people [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21711369/324364).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I posted before:

Meanwhile, I am right now having the problem with the `relenium` package, which can't locate `rJava`.

Version mismatches can bedevil you.  Check that if your version of R is 32 byte, so must your Java version be. Or, 64 byte must match 64 byte.

Second, I ended up adding to my PATH (I am on Windows 8) the location of the jv.dll file that XLConnect needs (I think that was the name of the file). I found the PATH through Control Panel and System Environment (and maybe more).

Third, the Java site will verify that you have Java installed.

Fourth, with the matching architecture and the PATH pointing to the needed .dll file, I rebooted and it all worked.

Good luck.