# how to include a java dependency for an R package

Tags: java, r, package, devtools, rjava

I have an R package that interacts with a java dependency (jar file) via the `rJava` package. I have no issues making things work when developing, but I don't know how to get the package installer to keep the jars with the installation in some sort of java src directory (e.g., `file.path(.libPaths()[1], "mypackage", "java")`. Is this possible without needing to write custom configuration files?

I am attempting to install using `devtools::install_git`. My source data is organized like most other R packages (I'm using the other features of `devtools` as well) except that I have an additional subdirectory `java` where my java dependencies are stashed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the `jar` files in `/inst/java` and have something like the following in `zzz.R`

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  .jpackage(name = pkgname, jars = "*")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Although for windows I needed to add a few lines to the `.onLoad` function as suggested by user2161065 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r)

Comment: What additions did user2161065 suggest, can you add them to the answer?

Comment: @jdharrison - thank you. saved me many hours. i can't figure out why it hasn't been mentioned in any doc.