# Installing a package gives Error loading rJava: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava'

Tags: r, rjava

I have made a package that uses `XLConnect`. I can correctly install it here. However, when I try to install it on someone elses PC, I get an `.onLoad failed` error. At first I got the `.onload Failed` error also when I did `library('rJava')`, but after installing the 64-bit version of Java `libraray(rJava)` now works correctly. However, when trying to install my package I still get the same load error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dirname(this$RuntimeLib)
  error: a character vector argument expected
Error : package 'XLConnect' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
```

both `library(XLConnect)` and `library(rJava)` work. Is there something else that can cause these types of errors?

Comment: Why do you use `.onLoad`?  If your package is dependent on another package, you should declare this as DEPENDS or IMPORTS in your DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE.  `.onLoad` should not be necessary.

Comment: @Andrie I'm not using `.onLoad`, I have it in the DESCRIPTION in `Depends`. This is the error I get when I try to install the package that has `XLConnect` in the DEPENDS.

Comment: Do you have this package on github or some other public repository?

Comment: @Andrie No I'm installing it from source. The dependent libraries are installed separately before installing the package.

Comment: I mean - can I view your code somewhere?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r/7604469