# Cant install openNLPdata_1.5.3-1.tar.gz on R/RStudio

Tags: java, r, opennlp, rjava

I'm trying install openNLPdata_1.5.3-1 but I cant get it done. I installed successfully the rJava dependencies.

I am getting this error:

```
 install.packages("C:/Users/André Almeida/Dropbox/Tese de Mestrado/R/packages/openNLPdata_1.5.3-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package 'openNLPdata' ...
** package 'openNLPdata' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  'openNLPdata' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: library.dynam("rJava", pkgname, libname)
  error: DLL 'rJava' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/library/openNLPdata'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\library" "C:/Users/ANDRAL~1/Dropbox/TESEDE~1/R/packages/openNLPdata_1.5.3-1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/ANDRAL~1/Dropbox/TESEDE~1/R/packages/openNLPdata_1.5.3-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: It's saying you don't have rJava (or at least don't have it for the x64 arch). Did you think you did?

Comment: You may also need to run `R CMD javareconf` from the command line.

Comment: @BondedDust its strange because i can load rJava perfectly.

i have rJava.dll in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\library\rJava\libs\x64. so i think i have rJava for x64.

i verified something strange. the dirs in next image (https://www.dropbox.com/s/11ej47i80c4okb7/rstudio.png) i dont have it, i just have ...\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll

Comment: Right, but is it 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: You may want to look at this SO posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r

Comment: x64.

But i'm start thinking that maybe after all rJava is not installed (Installation Log: http://pastebin.com/xyRVBbVD).

I'm so confused lol. any help will be welcome

Comment: already solved, tried a full reinstall and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. 
So it all goes down to rJava.

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Users/alexanderkozhevin/anaconda/lib/R/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘openNLPdata’
* removing ‘/Users/alexanderkozhevin/anaconda/lib/R/library/openNLPdata’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openNLPdata’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/1x/h3k01wvs1qq4sm4k_5z8qg9w0000gn/T/RtmpIrOVhy/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```