# Error loading xlsx library in R

Tags: r

Can someone please help me get around the problem I am having with xlsx

I successfully installed the package xlsx in R. however when I load the xlsx library I keep getting the following error.  I uninstalled Java, restarted PC and re-installed the latest Java version but that didnt fix the problem.  Thanks in advance

I am running R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Operating system : Windows 7 professional, SP 1
Java version 1.8.0_25 (latest)

"package ‘xlsx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Mathan\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6BDr2b\downloaded_packages

> library("xlsx")
>   Loading required package: rJava
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
>   Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded"

Comment: Did you try googling this?? You need to have a version of Java (e.g. 32 or 64 bit) that is consistent with your R version. That is what "architecture" means in the error message. See: http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/

Comment: Are you using 64-bit R and 32-bit Java?  This could be the cause.

Comment: thanks Steven and jlhoward.  I was in fact  using 64 bit R and 32 bit java.  However setting Java home in Sys.setenv didnt fix the problem.

Comment: options(java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_25")
library("rJava") worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was using 64 bit R and 32 bit Windows and that was causing the problem.

I got it working by setting
options(java.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25")
library("xlsx")

The following links were helpful: 
http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/
[Using the rJava package on Win7 64 bit with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r)

thanks to Steven and jlhoward for their help