# Error (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) to install rjava

Tags: r, rjava

I am installing rJava on a 64bit machine, running Windows 7, and am encountering the weirdest message. Below is the log. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks in advance.

```
install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/laila.rothe/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/rJava_0.9-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 761928 bytes (744 KB)
downloaded 744 KB
package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\laila.rothe\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmcecQy\downloaded_packages
library(rJava)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/laila.rothe/Documents
R/win-library/3.2/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Comment: You might find answer here - [Using the rJava package on Win7 64 bit with R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r)

Comment: I had a similar problem and it was due to rJava looking for x32 Java, where as my system was 64-bit. Go to [Java website and download a 64 bit version](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) and  then try reinstalling. I didnt need to alther the PATH variables manually. [more info](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/)