# Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace for 'rJava' in R's "XLConnect"

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

![enter image description here][1]![Hi All,

I'm working with the following R System:

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)][2]

I seem to be getting this error frequently on my laptop (description below). 
HP G60 Notebook PC
Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4400 @ 2.20GHz
RAM 4GB
64-bit

I'm trying to use the function "loadWorkbook" to upload an excel file, but it returns the error in the image. I updated Java and R (recommendation from other posts) and re-ran the program, but it returns that error. I've also done install.packages(XL Connect, dependencies = TRUE).

Any help would be appreciated. I'll be glad to give more details if need be.

The error is the following: 
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava'., details:
  call: dirname(this$RuntimeLib)
  error: a character vector argument expected

Also, the function works on my Surface 3 but not on my laptop. I'm sure it's something with my laptop, I just can't pinpoint it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the  correct java installed? I think you need the JRE kit.

Comment: Have you tried the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r