# I am getting an error jvm.dll file is missing although it is present in jre folder

Tags: java, r

I try to run my code in R which involves calling rJava library but I am unable to do so

```
> library(rJava)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/ALGO2/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Comment: It says jvm.dll file is missing although it is present in my jre folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r might help