# rJava on windows

Tags: java, r

I am trying to install rJava on windows.

I have looked this thread: [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r)
and set the PATH variable but it still doesn't work.
I notice that it catches with the error message:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/Portable/R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

the java I have installed is jre and jdk 1.8.0_20
is that a problem?

Comment: JRE/JDK is fine. Does it match your architecture? If you are using a 64 bit R, you need to have a 64 bit java as well.

Comment: How do I check my architecture? I also have 3.1.0 installed and am using R 3.2.3 via R portable if that makes a difference?

Comment: I had the same problem just today and solved it by installing JRE. Not sure if it applies to you based on Romans comment, but maybe try upgrading it?

Comment: Hmmm k I can upgrade mine but corporate policy prevents me from upgrade from others is there an alternative way?

Comment: `sessionInfo()` lists this in the second line.

Comment: I get `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`