# RWeka - J48 Function In R 3.3.0

Tags: r, decision-tree, rweka

I am working on a churn project and came across a J48 tree function. The asked packages were RWeka and party. But when I am loading library(RWeka), I am getting an error

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/joe.main/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘RWeka’ was built under R version 3.3.1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’
```

Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: It seems that the problem is the loading in the namespace of `rJava`, have you installed it correctly? 
If you have problems installing it try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of JAVA_HOME> It worked once I removed it from the Path in Environmental Variables