# Problems installing Deducer

Tags: r, rjava, deducer

I am trying to use Deducer in R Gui 64 bit (version 3.4  Windows 10). (I'd like to be able to use it in R Studio but am I right in understanding that you can't?)

Deducer, JGR and Rjava seem to install fine but when I call the JGR library, I get a warning message.

I have the most updated version of Java.

I have spent ages trying to work out the problem but am struggling. Any help would be very appreciated!

If I can use Deducer in R Studio, I'd be grateful if someone could advise if this is possible.

Here

```
    > library (JGR)
    Loading required package: rJava
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
     .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
      call: fun(libname, pkgname)
      error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
      Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded


    > library(rJava)
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
    call: fun(libname, pkgname)
    error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

Comment: Type the following command within R `system("java -version")` and then post the output.

Comment: > system("java -version")
        java version "1.8.0_131"
       Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
       Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode, 
        sharing)

Comment: @Marco Sandri  - thank you for replying!

Comment: I suggest to check if you have a 64bit version of JVM. It seems that you have a 32bit version installed. You shold also consider this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I launched the R 32 bit and all was fine. Many thanks!