# XLConnect package does not work R

Tags: java, r, xlconnect

System: Windows 10 Pro x64

R Version:

> "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

A couple of days ago I removed java_64_bit from my computer and  installed java_32_bit for another program. After that my code in R that uses XLConnect package stop working. I installed.

Then I reinstalled the java_64_bit in the following directory

> "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_181/")

and changed the Java Home in my R code

> Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_181/")

After installing and reinstalling the packages `rJava, XLConnectJars, XLConnect` I still get an error message.

```
    > library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung.

Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘XLConnect’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
2: package ‘XLConnectJars’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

When typing the command `java_version` I get

```
> > system("java -version") java version "1.8.0_181" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13) 
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: hi, did you already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r)? It seems a like similar problem

Comment: yes, all steps are done and everything should be correct. Still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The `JAVA_HOME` path you pasted in your question is the path for the 32-bits JRE.

Did you also try `C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/` where the 64-bits executables are placed?