# java cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

i had an error although i compiled Semester1 class and they are at the same package

```
public class Semester2{
 String subjects2[] = {"Arabic 2","Islamic 2","English 2","calculas","java1","manegment","physecs2"};
        double degrees2[] = new double [7];
        int hours2[] = {2,2,2,4,4,2,3};
        double subjectpoint2[] = new double[7];
                String[]estimate2 = new String[7];
                double fullDegree2 = 0;
                int fail2 = 0;  //fail subjects
        public Semester2(){
        }
        public Semester2(double degrees2[],String subjects2[]){
                    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
                        this .degrees2[i] = degrees2[i];
                        subjectpoint2[i] = degrees2[i] / 25;

                        fullDegree2 = 0;
                        fail2 = 0;
                    } //end of for
       } //end of constructer
                 public double Semester2Method(double degrees2[],String subjects2[],String[]estimate2,double fullDegree2,int fail2,double subjectpoint2[],int hours2[]){
                     for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
                        if ((degrees2[i] > 100)|(degrees2[i] < 0)){
                         System.out.println("this degree is imposible");
                         i--;
                         continue;
                     } //end of if
               if (degrees2[i] < 40)
                 fail2 ++;
               else
                  if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 3.6)
                   estimate2[i]="A+";
                  if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 3.2)
                   estimate2[i] = "A";
                    if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 2.8)
                   estimate2[i] = "B+";
                   if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 2.6)
                   estimate2[i] = "B";
                   if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 2.4)
                   estimate2[i] = "C+";
                   if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 2.0)
                   estimate2[i] = "C";
                   if (subjectpoint2[i] >= 1.6)
                   estimate2[i] = "D";
                   else

                   estimate2[i] = "F";
                  fullDegree2 += subjectpoint2[i] * hours2[i];
                  }//end of for
                 Semester1 [] obj=new Semester1[2];
                  obj[0]=new Semester1();
                  obj[1]=new Semester1(degrees[7],subjects[7]);
                 //Semester1 obj = new Semester1();

                 double avarge = fullDegree2 /19;
                 double cavarge=( fullDegree2 + obj[1].fullDegree )/( 21 + 19 );
                 return cavarge;

             } //end of the method
         } //end of semester2
```

here is the error 
  error: cannot find symbol

```
Semester1 [] obj=new Semester1[2];
                 ^
```

Comment: Do you have an object called `Semester1`?

Comment: They are in the same package in the same project? And is your class really called `Semester1`? Please check it for typos.

Comment: Your class name is Semester2. There is a typo.

Comment: no the object name is obj but the class is Semester1 , yes my class name is really Semester1

Comment: What is the Semester1, is it class??

Comment: how do you compile your 2 classes?

Comment: compiled the first class by ctrl+1 and then the other  , did you mean that??

Comment: ctrl+1? Do you use an IDE like eclipse/netbeans/...? Or do you execute javac from command line?

Comment: Do you even find a Semester1.class file anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Semester1.java` file has not been compiled, as I can guess from your comments. You need to first compile that file. That would create `Semester1.class` file. Then you should compile `Semester2.java`. I think this should work.

Comment: i got it but when i compile file Semester1 it did not create Semester1.class but create Semester1.java

Comment: `Semester1.java` is the source code of the file. you need to compile it. Tell me how you are compiling it...

Comment: @azza: You're definitely confused somewhere.  `Semester1.java` should be the (text) file that **you** created, containing the source code for that class.  That's the file that you *supply* to the compiler; the compiler will never create it.  Instead it'll create a `Semester1.class` file which contains the compiled output.

Comment: @azza You need to compile Semester1.java using `javac Semester1.java` in the command line

Comment: javac not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or patch file

Comment: Well well well. Then how do you compile?

Comment: i did what you tell me to do and that what i got at command line

Comment: @azza See this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1678520/4121347 and remove the error and then do `javac Semester1.java`

Answer (score 0):

check if Semester1.class file is created by checking in the file directory

Comment: ifound .java class but didn't find .class file but i dont know how to creat it am new

Comment: in command prompt navigate to the path of java file and type "java Semester1.java" without the double qoutes

Comment: couldn't find or loud main class Semester1.java

Comment: i did that but i got (javac not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or patch file)