# working directory good to be in the 'C' drive or any other drive.?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Version: Juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426. I installed & configured JDK 8 and JRE 8 properly the same did check in the command prompt. i can run programs using notepads .java extension but where i am unable to run .java extension that are inside of project src. (eclipse working directory)

```
javac: file not found: Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

i properly set up environment variables in the System variables

```
PATH :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin; user variables 
CLASSPATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;. 
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

Now i am using maven dependencies it throws error 'source not found' message in red color and next line 'edit source look up path'.

if my working directory in different drive how can JVM finds if i dont provide directory path in the System variables/user variables?

Comment: what is your system: ubuntu / windows / etc ?

Comment: windows 10 64bit OS.

Comment: It seems you need to correct the path in the system. Also, you can see this resources, here is a good example how to write a system path in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678520/javac-not-working-in-windows-command-prompt and official resource: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html

Comment: My working directory is different so i did set classpath accordingly. by navigating through environment variables-->user variables. its fine.