# c# WPF application use CLI questions

Tags: c#, wpf

i use c# to create WPF,i want to use dos with my application。and to get output。
my code ：

```
process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ".";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //Process.Start("cmd.exe");
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"c:");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"help");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"javac");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"dir");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"adb shell");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"ipconfig");
            //process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

dos command is regular。but my java command is nothing。below my result：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUurP.png)

i hope someone can help me.thank you.

Comment: For future questions, please pay close attention to the tags you select. The `c` tag (which you selected) is not the same as the `c#` tag (which I've set with an edit).

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678520/javac-not-working-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: If you don't tell javac what to compile then it doesn't have anything to do.