# javac command only usable if I open CMD in the user folder

Tags: java, cmd, path, windows-10

I'm trying to setup my PATH correctly so I can use javac in my "Java" folder. When I open CMD it opens in C:\Users\User where java and javac work. If I cd to another folder they still both work, however if I open CMD in for example C:\Users\User\Java by opening the folder directly in CMD with Atom it suddenly doesn't recognize the javac command anymore, even though it still recognizes the java command.

Can anyone please tell me how I can make the javac command work in any folder, just like the java command without having to cd to the folder everytime.

EDIT: I've been linked to 2 different stackoverflow questions which I have already tried, they let me use the javac command when opening CMD normally, but if I open CMD through for example Atom in a folder (so it opens in C:\Users\User\Java) it doesn't recognize javac.

Comment: Check this out. Well explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678520/javac-not-working-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javac not working in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678520/javac-not-working-in-windows-command-prompt)